# CSS Layout with checkboxes

Tags: css, checkbox

I'm having an issue with my layout when I want to add checkboxes.

CSS:

```
p label {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    /*display: block;
    padding-top: 8px;
    float: left;*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="a">a:</label>
    <select name="a" id="a" class="select">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="s">s:</label>
    <select name="s" id="s" class="select">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="d">d:</label>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="looking_for[]" value="1" />
    <label class="no_float" for="1">Friends</label>
    <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="looking_for[]" value="2" />
    <label for="2">Friends</label>
</p>
```

I'm wanting it to look something like

[image: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/images/web-form-design-patterns/labels-small.jpg]

I've added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LW8D/) for convenience.

Comment: "403 Forbidden" when open "this" link.

Comment: Image url is giving forbidden. So plz allow us to show it :)

Comment: Easiest way is to use 'table', and give fixed width to 'select' elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3LW8D/1/ Might be done with less `div`s and more css but since the image link doesn't work i'am just guessing what you are lookign for. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have used "id=1 and id=2" for your checkboxes. This can be one reason since numbers don't work for id's.
Try to give a meaningful name, some character or string.

Comment: Yes I know but that wouldn't effect the layout.

Comment: you are asking for handling checkboxes and showing us the radio buttons/option button.

Comment: He asked for layout like that on picture, with checkboxes instead radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you meant,

http://jsfiddle.net/3LW8D/3/

```
use container div.
```

and yeah even though the answer given by "user1823799" looks strikingly similar, there is a considerable difference in approach, the paragraph tag is messed in his example, so I just reinvented the wheel.

and coming back to your problem, always make a container div with a specific size, make sure that its positioned correctly in the place you want your elements located, if position isn't correct, then you could use margin/position property to fix it, then nest your small elements in this container div.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for you

a:
    
        Choose

s:
    
        Choose

d:

```
<input id="first" type="checkbox" name="looking_for[]" value="1" />Friends<br />

<input id="second" type="checkbox" name="looking_for[]" value="2" />Friends<br />

</p>
```

And the css goes like this

```
p label {
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100px;
display: inline-block;}

#second{margin-left:108px;}

/*display: block;
padding-top: 8px;
float: left;*/
}
```